# Volley onErrorResponse getString occassionally returns null

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-volley

Be great if someone can share a solution to this seemingly simple problem, as my app crashes when attempting to get a *String Resource* using the following line in my application within the onErrorResponse section of a simple Volley request:

```
mTextView.setText(sActivity.getString(R.string.connection_error, 
customMessageParameter));
```

This issue appears to only occur for some users (despite attempting to replicate the crash myself), which is reported via [Fabric](https://fabric.io), namely the following:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual 
method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getString(int)' on a null 
object reference at 
com.appname.MyFragment$13.onErrorResponse(MyFragment.java:651)
```

I ensure the *Activity* ***sActivity*** variable is initialised using the following function, which is invoked in each lifecycle call from *onAttach* to ensure it's available:

```
private void setActivity(Activity activity, Context context) {
    if (activity != null) {
        sActivity = activity;
    } else if (getActivity() != null) {
        sActivity = getActivity();
    } else if (context != null) {
        sActivity = (Activity) context;
    }
}
```

I understand how to check the *getString()* call is not equal to null beforehand and how this can ensure the app will not crash, yet I need to obtain dynamic values from the *String Resources* at run-time that will vary.

From what I've gathered, the activity instance can vary using asynchronous network calls that can result in this issue. I've also considered simply using *getString()* on its own and also *getResources().getString()*, yet I'm unsure if this will prevent the issue from arising.

Answer (score 1):

You should not pass the activity to the fragment and store it that way, this is likely the cause of your problem. Just use `getActivity()` from inside the fragment.

Also, your setActivity code does not necesarilly guarantee that `sActivity` won't be null. What happens if all 3 conditionals happen to be null? There is no final else to catch the situation where all 3 are null. Plus, Android can be funky sometimes while fragments/activites are inflating. Theres a good chance all 3 of those variables are null at the time of OnAttach. Either way, `getActivity()` should return what you need if you use it in the OnCreate or after the Fragment has fully been inflated. You shouldn't have an activity variable since getActivity does exactly what you need, and what happens when the activity changes but you have an older version of it stored in memory that you try to call methods on?

Also, use `getResources().getString()`, since you are getting the string from your string resources.

To summarize, your line of code should look like this instead (with no need for your `setActivity` method or `sActivity` variable).

`getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.connection_error)`

It's been a while, so let me know if this doesn't work for you and I can try to help you further.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I will give that a try directly as I haven't tried that combination yet, especially considering using getActivity() to get the current activity that may obviously change. The only reason for the setActivity() method is due to initially passing in the context generated from the onAttach lifecycle call, which is where is recommended to get the activity instance, if not the onActivityCreated lifecycle call. I will update to mark your suggestion as the answer once I've assumed it's solved the issue.